# What's the difference in chemical potentials between nearly free electron model and tight-binding model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, chemical-potential, tight-binding

In nearly free electron model, we know that when temperature is zero, the chemical potential $\mu$ is same as the Fermi energy $E_F$, $\mu=E_F$. For a good metal, $E_F$ is roughly $10\mathrm{eV}$, so that the chemical potential is $10\mathrm{eV}$.

However, for the tight-binding model in simple cubic lattice, the dispersion is $\xi_\mathbf{k}=-2t[\cos(k_x)+\cos(k_y)+\cos(k_z)]-\mu$. When the syetem is half-filled (which is a metal), the chemical potential $\mu$ is zero.

I don't know why the chemical potentials in above two models are different. Aren't they both can be corresponding to free electron model?